# Deserialize XML using list<Object>

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, windows-phone-8

there my XMl file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="XnaCzyMap.Element[]">
    <Element>
    <id>5</id>
    <pos_x>54</pos_x>
    <pos_y>30</pos_y>
    <rot>90</rot>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <id>5</id>
    <pos_x>54</pos_x>
    <pos_y>165</pos_y>
    <rot>90</rot>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <id>5</id>
    <pos_x>54</pos_x>
    <pos_y>340</pos_y>
    <rot>25</rot>
  </Element>
    </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

And my class :

```
public class Element
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("pos_x")]
    public int pos_x { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("pos_y")]
    public int pos_y { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("rot")]
    public int rot { get; set; }
}
```

I want to Deserialize my XML as a collection of "Element". it worked when i didn't use XNA, but its not working anymore. VS give me the following error : `Error    1   There was an error while deserializing intermediate XML. Cannot find type "XnaCzyMap.Element".`

I have tried to add a collection as class but don"t work either.

```
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("XnaContent")]
    public class Elements
    {
        [XmlElement("Element")]
        public List<Element> listObjet { get; set; }

    }
```

What is the difference between deserialize using Xna or not ?

The code that do the deserialization :

```
  public void load_map(string path)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Element[]));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            try
            {
                file = (Element[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

I have tried to switch "Element[]" by "Elements" when i tried with "Elements class"

Comment: Are you sure your class `Element` is declared in the namespace `XnaCzyMap`?

Comment: yes sure, i have only one Namespace for all my project i guess.  namespace XnaCzyMap
{
    public class Element
    { ....}}

Comment: Ask me if you need more precision about my code or anything. I need to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

Xna is not interfering with the serialization but you have minor errors in your code.

Your code is correct but the XML file you are using is not formed correctly. When in doubt about the expected format of the XML file, try using the XmlSerializer's Serialize method to create the format that is expected.

In this case, to make this work, you must change the XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfElement Type="XnaCzyMap.Element[]">
    <Element>
    <id>5</id>
    <pos_x>54</pos_x>
    <pos_y>30</pos_y>
    <rot>90</rot>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <id>5</id>
    <pos_x>54</pos_x>
    <pos_y>165</pos_y>
    <rot>90</rot>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <id>5</id>
    <pos_x>54</pos_x>
    <pos_y>340</pos_y>
    <rot>25</rot>
  </Element>
</ArrayOfElement>
```

Notice how I changed the root tag. Its name (ArrayOfElement) is important to .NET.

Edit:
In case you want to keep your original XML file, that's fine, but you must change several errors in your code.

1. The XmlSerializer construct will take typeof(Elements) as parameter, not typeof(Element[]) and also change the return-type cast appropriately. You mentioned you did this.
2. Change this attribute near targeting the listObjet collection [XmlElement("Element")] into this one [XmlElement("Asset")]. This attribute does not say what the members of the collection will look like in the XML. It says what name will the entire collection have.

Comment: May I ask are you sure Type="XnaCzyMap.Element[] is correct? shouldn't that be Type="XnaCzyMap.Element? (I ask as I am not sure myself)

Comment: I think so, yes. I've actually created the project and debugged it in Visual Studio, it ran with no problems.

Comment: Did you run it with Xna ? cause i have the following error"XnaContent is missing" And when i add it, the next error message is : "XML element "Asset" not found". Kind of errors that i didn"t while not using XNA.

Comment: I did. This is not XNA-related. Verify that you load the appropriate file with the correct format. If you are unsure whether your XML file is correct, first try to serialize the object and take a look at the generated file.